# After JS append a <li> in existing <ul>, i cannot selected it with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, html-lists, selector

I have a dropdown list (Bootstrap), after selected an element in this dropdown list, i call a php file with ajax to load a specific content for a new dropdown list.

In my JS script i append the result i found in a existing ul list.

My problem is after append new li element in my ul list #submitPoint, i cannot select them with selector from js.
I don't know why but JS seem to not see the new elements he just append before..

Here the PhP code with 2 dropdown list, one for flow name, other one for flow's submit point:

```
print "<div class='row'>" ;
print "<div id='flowsPane' class='col-sm-6' style='display: true;'>" ;
print "<div class='btn-group'>" ;
print "<a id='dropdownText1' class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>Select a Flow <span class='caret'></span></a>" ;
print("<ul id='flows' class='dropdown-menu'>");
foreach ($flows as $flow) {
    print("<li id='" . $flow . "'>" . $client->getNameOfFlow($flow) . "</li>");
}
print "</ul>" ;
print "</div>" ;
print "</div>" ;
print "<div id='submitPointPane' class='col-sm-6' style='display: none;'>" ;
print "<div class='btn-group'>" ;
print "<a id='dropdownText2' class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>Select a SubmitPoint <span class='caret'></span></a>" ;
print("<ul id='submitPoint' class='dropdown-menu'>");
```

Here the JS code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#flows li ").click(function(e){
            var flow = $(this).text();
            //window.alert(flow);
            document.getElementById('dropdownText1').innerHTML = flow + ' <span class="caret"></span>';
        });

        $('#flows li').click(function(e) {
            $("#submitPointPane").show();
            //window.alert(e.target.id);
            var post_url = "include/submitpoint_list.php";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: post_url,
                data: {'flowId': e.target.id},
                dataType: 'json ',
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#submitPoint").empty();
                    var ite = 0;
                    while (ite < data.length) {
                        $("#submitPoint").append("<li>" + data[ite] + "</li>");
                        //document.getElementById('submitPoint').innerHTML = "<li>" + data[ite] + "</li>";
                        ite++;
                    }
                    return false;
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    window.alert("error " + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
            //return false;
        });
        $("#submitPoint li").click(function(e){
            var sp = $(this).text();
            window.alert(sp);
            document.getElementById('dropdownText2').innerHTML = sp + ' <span class="caret"></span>';
        });
    });
</script>
```

So after append `li` element in `ul #submitPoint`, if I click on it, the `#submitPoint li` click function is never call, but the `li` element appear in my list....
(Sorry I cannot add picture)

Do you have any ideas that can help me to the question why the JQuery selector does not work properly for the new `li` element append?
Thanks for all!

Comment: I'd change `click(` to `on('click',`

Comment: I would be helpful if you have provided the HTML output, not the PHP source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you're experiencing is caused by the simple fact, that your dynamically created `<li>` item doesn't have an even listener for click event attached.

What you need is to use `.on()` method, to attach an event listener fod dynamically created elements.

```
// The event listener is being applied to the parent.
$('#flows').on('click', 'li', callback);
```

Comment: when you write callback, you mean =>

$("#submitPoint li").on('click', 'li', function(e){
            var sp = $(this).text();
            window.alert(sp);
            document.getElementById('dropdownText2').innerHTML = sp + ' <span class="caret"></span>';
        });

Comment: @ChampinNéaultFlorian yes, that's right.

Comment: Guys You are awesome, thank to you, i have been in trouble for hours, and you solve this in 10 minutes, thanks !
Everything work properly now ! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.on()` method to bind event listeners to elements that exist now and in the future. http://api.jquery.com/on/